# Normal Function, Limit Ordinals and Composition of functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(ZF) We say that the formula operation F is normal if:

• for each ordinal α, F(α) is an ordinal as well,

• F is strictly increasing over the ordinals:
α < β ⇒ F(α) < F(β),

• F is continious over the limit ordinals:
Lim(λ) ⇒ F(λ) = sup{F(β) | β < λ}.

*а) Let F is a normal function. Prove that for every ordinal α the following statements are true:*

1. α ≤ F(α);
2. for each limit ordinal λ, F(λ) is a limit ordinal as well;
3. for every non empty set A of ordinals is true that:

sup{F(α) | α ∈ A} = F(sup A), i.e.:
∪{F(α) | α ∈ A} = F(∪A);

4. each time when F(0) < β it follows that there exists a largest ordinal α which satisfies: F(α) ≤ β.

*b) Prove that the composition of normal functional operations is normal as well,i.e. if the formula operations F и G are normal,then the formula operation H, defined as x с H(x) = G(F(x)),
is normal as well.*

My ideas are:
a)

1.To use that if  α, β ordinals and α < β ↔ S(α) ≤ β, where S(α) is the successor of the ordinal number α. But S(α) is defined as α∪{α}, hence α∪{α}≤ β. Also, I claim that between an ordinal α and its successor S(α) there is no other ordinal. Hence let S(α):=F(α) which gives us α<F(α).

2. Every non zero  ordinal which is not a successor ordinal is a limit ordinal:
   Limit(λ) ↔ (λ != 0 & (∀ β)[λ!= S(β)]).Let now x ∈ λ is an arbitrary. Hence ord(x) and ord(S(x)).Since the successor of x is the smallest ordinal bigger than x, we have that S(x) ≤ λ. But λ is not a successor, so S(x) < λ.Then Lim(λ) ⇒ F(λ) = sup{F(x) | x < λ}, so F maps all ordinals bigger than x into limit ordinals.

3.We say that a is an upper bound for B in <A, R> if for (∀ x )[x ∈ B → <x , a> ∈ R] where <A, R> is a partial ordered set with B ⊆ A and a ∈ A; As such F will map a to sup<A,R> in (B). About unity, i think that induction will solve it for two or more ordinals.

4. Since 0 is not an ordinal, our function F can be initialized as F(α) = 1 + α. Hence F(0) = 1 < β. But for every successor α of 1, we have that α < α∪{α}=F(α) <β;

For b): It seems obvious that the composition of normal functions is a normal functuons since Dom and Rng are the ordinal numbers, but can I use somehow the Bachmann hierarchy here?

I am sorry for this long post, but in my opinion if I have divided it into two separated posts, the whole idea wouldn't have been fulfilled.
I would be extremely thankful for any help you give me!

Answer (score 1):

This has quite a few problems. For (a) you need to show that **every** normal function satisfies (1), (2), (3), and (4). Thus, you cannot ‘let $S(\alpha):=F(\alpha)$, as you do in your argument for (1): your $S$ is the successor function, so $S(\alpha)$ is already defined, and there is no reason to think that it is $F(\alpha)$. (And in any case $S$ is not a normal function.)

Your conclusion for (2) is a non sequitur: it doesn’t follow from your argument. It’s also false in general: a normal function need not map all sufficiently large ordinals to limit ordinals. You have no argument for (3), and for (4) you are once again assuming a particular $F$ (which is not in fact normal) rather than proving something about **all** normal functions. And $0$ **is** an ordinal.

Let $F$ be normal, and suppose that $F(\alpha)<\alpha$ for some $\alpha$. Let $$A=\{\xi\le\alpha:F(\xi)<\xi\}\,;$$ $A$ is a non-empty set of ordinals, so it has a least element $\mu$. Let $\beta=F(\mu)$; $\beta<\mu$, so $F(\beta)<F(\mu)=\beta$, and therefore $\beta\in A$. But this is impossible: $\mu$ is the smallest member of $A$, and $\beta<\mu$. This contradiction shows that $\alpha\le F(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha$.

Let $\lambda$ be a limit ordinal; since $F$ is normal, $F(\lambda)=\sup\{F(\beta):\beta<\lambda\}$. Suppose that this is not a limit ordinal. Clearly $F(\lambda)\ne 0$ (why?), so $F(\lambda)\ne 0$, and therefore $F(\lambda)=\alpha+1$ for some ordinal $\alpha$. (I write $\alpha+1$ for the immediate successor of $\alpha$.) Thus, $\sup\{F(\beta):\beta<\lambda\}=\alpha+1$. If it were the case that $F(\beta)\le\alpha$ for all $\beta<\lambda$, then $\sup\{F(\beta):\beta<\lambda\}$ would be at most $\alpha$, so there must be a $\gamma<\lambda$ such that $F(\gamma)=\alpha+1$. But $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal, so $\gamma+1<\lambda$, and $\gamma<\gamma+1$, so $$\alpha+1=F(\gamma)<F(\gamma+1)\le\sup\{F(\beta):\beta<\lambda\}=\alpha\,,$$ which is absurd. This contradiction shows that $F(\lambda)$ cannot be a successor ordinal, and since it’s not $0$, it must be a limit ordinal.

Now let $A$ be a non-empty set of ordinals; we want to show that $$\sup\{F(\alpha):\alpha\in A\}=F(\sup A)\,.\tag{1}$$ Let $\beta=\sup A$; then $\alpha\le\beta$ for each $\alpha\in A$, so $F(\alpha)\le F(\beta)$ for each $\alpha\in A$. That is, $F(\beta)$ is an upper bound for $\{F(\alpha):\alpha\in A\}$, so $$\sup\{F(\alpha):\alpha\in A\}\le F(\beta)\,.$$ There are now two possibilities. If $\beta\in A$, then $$F(\beta)\le\sup\{F(\alpha):\alpha\in A\}\le F(\beta)\,,$$ and $(1)$ holds. If $\beta\notin A$, then $\beta$ must be a limit ordinal (why?), and therefore

$$\begin{align*}
F(\beta)&=\sup\{F(\alpha):\alpha<\beta\}\\
&=\bigcup\{F(\alpha):\alpha\in\beta\}\\
&\overset{*}=\bigcup\{F(\alpha):\alpha\in A\}\\
&=\sup\{F(\alpha):\alpha\in A\}\,,
\end{align*}$$

giving us $(1)$ in this case as well. I leave it to you to prove the starred equality; prove and use the fact that for each $\gamma<\beta$ there is an $\alpha\in A$ such that $\gamma<\alpha$.

Finally, suppose that $F(0)<\beta$. Let $A=\{\alpha\le\beta:F(\alpha)<\beta\}$. From (1) we know that if $\alpha$ is an ordinal such that $F(\alpha)\le\beta$, then $\alpha\le\beta$, so the set $A$ contains every ordinal $\alpha$ such that $F(\alpha)\le\beta$, and we want to show that $A$ has a largest element. Let $\gamma=\sup A$. If $\gamma$ is $0$ or a successor ordinal, then $\gamma\in A$. If $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal, then by (3) we know that $$F(\gamma)=\sup\{F(\alpha):\alpha\in A\}\le\beta\,,$$ so again $\gamma\in A$. Thus, in all cases $A$ has a largest element, namely, $\gamma=\sup A$.

For (b) it is trivial that $H(\alpha)$ is an ordinal for every $\alpha$: $F$ is normal, so $F(\alpha)$ is an ordinal, and therefore $G\big(F(\alpha)\big)$ is defined and, because $G$ is normal, is an ordinal. It is also very easy to see that $H$ is strictly increasing: if $\alpha<\beta$, then $F(\alpha)<F(\beta)$, so $H(\alpha)=G\big(F(\alpha)\big)<G\big(F(\beta)\big)=H(\beta)$.

Finally, suppose that $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal. Then $F(\lambda)=\sup\{F(\alpha):\alpha<\lambda\}$. Now apply (4) to $G$:

$$\begin{align*}
H(\lambda)&=G\big(F(\lambda)\big)\\
&=\sup\left\{G\big(F(\alpha)\big):\alpha<\lambda\right\}\\
&=\sup\{H(\alpha):\alpha<\lambda\}\,.
\end{align*}$$

Thus, $H$ is normal.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the effort you have made to come up with this solution. About the tasks you gave me to prove on my own: 1)If F(λ)=0 then there exists λ<F(λ)=0-contradiction. 2) I assume the contrary, namely that for each x<β=supA there exists α<γ which means that  α belongs to γ.Then let β=F(γ)>γ for every γ. But Limit(β). Hence Limit(F(γ)), but γ belongs to β=> there does not exist Limitγ-absurd.

Comment: @Tiki: You’re welcome! Is (2) supposed to be a proof of the starred equality? If so, it’s quite a bit wide of the mark. Since $\beta\notin A$, we know that $A\subseteq\beta$, and therefore $$\bigcup\{F(\alpha):\alpha\in A\}\subseteq\bigcup\{F(\alpha):\alpha\in\beta\}\,.$$ Thus, we need to prove the opposite inclusion. To do this, we must show that if $\xi\in F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in\beta$, then $\xi\in F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in A$. We can do this by showing that for each $\gamma<\beta$ there is an $\alpha\in A$ such that $\gamma<\alpha$. If not, there is some $\gamma<\beta$ such ...

Comment: ... that $\alpha\le\gamma$ for every $\alpha\in A$. In other words, $\gamma$ is an upper bound for $A$, and hence $\gamma\le\sup A=\beta$. This is a contradiction, so there is no such $\gamma$.